# Is sp_getapplock recommended for long running locks (> 10 minutes)?

Tags: sql-server, locking, connections, max-connections

I'm trying to get rid of a Redis dependency in our application.

We notice that is worse for our uptime to have a dependency on both SQL and Redis, above the performance benefits Redis would give us.

The last part we need to fix is the *multi-instance locks*. Right now I use a wrapper called RedLock. See the code below:

```
using (var lock = RedisLocker.Create(key, expiryTime: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), waitTime: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), retryTime: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))) 
{
    if (!lock.IsAcquired)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't acquire lock");

    [code]
}
```

I want to replace this with a SQL alternative and came across `sp_getapplock`. I noticed that you actually have to keep the connection open to use sp_getapplock.

For short locks that feels fine, but for long locks (>10 minutes) it feels "expensive" to keep a connection open.

- Should I go for a polling strategy similar to the Redis version?
- Or is my assumption wrong that connections are expensive?
- I'm planning to wrap the code in something similar like the Redlock call - any other recommendations?

**Extra notes**

- Everything is running on Azure.
- The application is high traffic on peak moments and *can* have SQL performance problems.
- The lock is not in a high frequency path though (just a few processes).

Comment: Be aware that if the connection holding the long-running lock is severed, the lock will be released and is not a good pattern, especially in the cloud. This looks to be to be an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as holding a lock for 10 minutes on a cache entry has a smell about it.

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman, could be true - what would you recommend for allowing a long running process (mix C# + DB calls) to be run only once among all instances. Anything I can search for specifically on the internets?

Comment: Being a database guy, my first inclination would be to engineer a solution that updates a lock flag in a table to serialize the process. The challenge is addressing the unhappy path without manual intervention that ensures processing is rolled back and the flag reset in the event processing fails under various scenarios, which requires a deeper understanding of the process and implications. Maybe someone can chime in with a more robust solution or recommendation.